# Script bash write in a fifo and c program read from it

Tags: c, bash, pipe, fifo, writer

I have a bash script that writes to a fifo. And I have a C program that reads from the same fifo.

I am sure the script works because I've tried to read from the fifo with another script and everything worked. But something does not work in C program. When I run my script and when I run the C program it's like they await each other. Here's the code.

The script is (the writer):

```
#!/bin/bash

fifo_name="myfifo";

# Se non esiste, crea la fifo;
[ -p $fifo_name ] || mkfifo $fifo_name;

echo "3" > $fifo_name;
echo "6" > $fifo_name;
```

And here the c program (the reader) :

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define MAX_BUF 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd, i;
    char * myfifo = argv[1];
    char buf[MAX_BUF];

    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);

    while (1) {
        if(read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF) > 0)
        {
            printf("Received: %s\n", buf);      
        }
    }

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: For one, not checking the result of the `open()` call before assuming it worked and marching to the cliff. The failure to have an mechanism for breaking out of the `while` loop is sort of a bonus, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine, provided you do the following.

- Ensure that, when you run the C program, you provide an argument with the correct pathname to the FIFO file.
- Run the shell program first since it's the one that will create the FIFO file if it doesn't yet exist.

You can alleviatethe second problem by having the C program exit if the FIFO isn't already there, with something like:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define MAX_BUF 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd, i;
    char * myfifo = argv[1];
    char buf[MAX_BUF];

    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);

    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("opening fifo");
        return 1;
    }
    *buf = '0';
    while (strchr (buf,'x') ==NULL) {
        if((i = read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF)) > 0)
        {
            buf[i] = '\0';
            printf("Received: [%s]\n", buf);
        }
    }

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

You'll notice I've also allowed the shell script to terminate it if it sends through an `x` and I've also ensured the buffer is properly terminated for printing it as a string.

The (minor) changes to the shell script are:

```
#!/bin/bash

fifo_name="myfifo";

# Se non esiste, crea la fifo;
[ -p $fifo_name ] || mkfifo $fifo_name;

echo "3" > $fifo_name;
echo "6" > $fifo_name;
echo "x" > $fifo_name;
```

The output I see at the C end is then:

```
Received: [3
]
Received: [6
x
]
```

and you can see it's not always what you expect. The `read` call may pick up multiple sends in one hit since there's no real protocol layered on top. If you want to avoid that, you'll need to add your own protocol.

Comment: Yeah.. It was just a wong path between the script and the program C. But It still does not work like expected :(
I expect "Received:3 Received:6".... I obtain instead "Received: 3 6"... It would seem a stupid thing but i think that it means that I am reading the content of the fifo in one time!! It's link a need just a cycle of the loop... I expected at least 2 cycles... I hope i have bben clear

Comment: Infact If I remove the while I still print out the screen both written value... should be blocking instead... no? script write a row and stop someone read... program c read, script write a second time and bock again, program c read

Comment: @Ciccio, see my update, there is no inherent protocol in the messages. You could whack a `sleep 1` between each send but even that may not guarantee it. If you're sure the messages will be terminated with `\n`, you should use that for your protocol separator. You still may get muliple (or partial) messages in a single read, you'll just have to split them yourself.